# Delete restriction in a BindingSource binded to a list of objects

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects linked to a binding source, in this list each object has a property thay says if the user can remove the object from the list or not.

Is there a simple way to prevent or cancel deletion of an object from a list if this object has an especific value in a property?

This Class has a property called Tipo... if Tipo is not "M" It cannot be modified all of the other properties, I have achieved this in Set section of each property however I still dont kow how to prevent deletion from this objects in my list of Objects

```
public class SearchElement
{
    public string Tipo { get; set; } = "M";
    private string _Operador;
    private string _Andor;
    private string _Negacion;
    private object _Val1;
    private object _Val2;

    public string Operador
    {
        get
        {
            return _Operador;
        }
        set
        {
            //Only if Tipo is "M" (Manual) all of the properties can be modified
            if (Tipo == "M") { _Operador = value != null ? value.ToUpper() : null; }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you add some code so we know what you're trying to do?

Comment: I don't think so. You may need to disable deletion in the UI according to this property.

Comment: You mean `Enabled={Binding CanRemove}`. If you haven't got a bool property, you can use converter and implement your logic there

Comment: Could you please tell me more about this Binding CanRemove?